# What site would be on-topic for advice on database schema?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I feel it would be off topic for stackoverflow as it would be opinion based, where would advice on database schema be on-topic?

Comment: opinion based is off-topic pretty much everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, opinion-based questions are pretty much off-topic everywhere. There is a good reason for this.

The purpose of Stack Exchange, in regards to Q&A, is to provide high quality questions with definite answers. Asking for an opinion promotes discussion, and there really is no specific answer. Every user has their own opinion, so it becomes a popularity contest. We do not want questions that hold their merits in popularity; we want questions that hold their merits in quality and reliable answers.

Every Stack Exchange site has an automatic close flag for "primarily opinion based" - even Software Recommendations. No matter how on topic your question may be in subject, the very nature of being primarily opinion based would still leave it flagged and closed.

---

All is not lost! You do have other options.

1 - *Ask Stack Overflow*. [Jump on the their meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), and ask for help in improving your question. If you explain *what* you are trying to do, and what your *requirements* are, others may be able to help you formulate a better question. I have seen *heavy* opinion-based questions fixed to meet guidelines simply by adding very specific metrics of which to measure the value of various options. If we can compare options using metrics, rather than the merit of other's opinions, we don't really have an opinion-based question anymore. Again, you need to ask about this at the Stack Overflow meta.

2 - *Ask in chat*. Jump on the Stack Overflow chat, and simply ask the users currently in the chat room. Someone might even be interested in opening a private chat room to discuss the options.